# Trying to install MultiDoge wallet, and get the message "Java not installed"

Tags: java

I am trying to create a MultiDoge wallet. It's supposed to be so easy!!!!

I downloaded MultiDoge, no problem. Tried to install it (multidoge-0.1.7-windows-setup.exe), but I was informed that Java is not installed. So I downloaded Java, no problem. I installed it, no problem. Get the message "You have successfully installed Java. If I check in the Control Panel I see "jre-8u281-windows-x64.exe". I assume that means that it's loaded. Tried to install multidoge-0.1.7-windows-setup.exe again. Get the message "Java was not installed" Google the problem, I get the following answer, "Enable Java in the browser through the Java Control Panel" Where is the Java Control Panel? And how do I open it when I'm informed "Java is not installed' Why is everything made so complicated? Any advice would be much appreciated.
PS I'm not certain if this is relevant, but I am using the Brave Browser with the Google search engin

Comment: Sounds like a system variable issue.  Reinstalling Java probably is the simplest solution

Comment: Thanks I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

I am late to this question, but hopefully it can help others.
In your system environment variable you have to add manually JAVA_HOME
And the folder where it is located, e.g `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_311\bin`

Answer (score -1):

You just need to specify the environment variables of your Java version:

Enter the environment variables your version of Java. You can find out the version by going to the folder with Java installed. Example: C:\Program Files\Javamultidoge env3
In the Variable name field, enter: `JAVA_HOME`

In Variable value: `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_341\bin`

If you have a different version, then instead of jre1.8.0_341, enter the name of your folder.

See [example here for Multidoge with images](https://miningsoft.org/en/guide/multidoge/#Step%202%20-%20Specify%20Java%20Environment%20Variables)

Comment: The image you have tried to attached is located on your personal machine. We cannot view it. Please try uploading it to Imgur.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).